# Laravel 8. Объединение моделей

Tags: php, laravel, request, eloquent

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется такая структура данных. 3 модели

Требуется получать модель User в виде JSON с дополнительными полями в зависимости от типа пользователя.

К примеру User имеет поле Type(Client). По запросу User::whereEmail(email)->first();
должно вернуть поля пользователя, а также поля другой модели которой он принадлежит.

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее будет создать промежуточную модель Role,и привязать к модели User(если роль 1 то 1 к 1, если ролей может быть несколько то 1 ко многим)

```
 public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'users_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

Это в модели User.(если у вас 1 ко многим) Тогда при запросе `User::whereEmail(email)->with('roles')->first()`
будет возвращаться User c нужными вам полями..(то что Client и Manager,это роли, думаю объяснять не надо?)
Ну а если сильно хочется держать их отдельными моделями, то эти модели(client,manager) привязать к модели Role.В модели Role в этом случае, можно написать метод, который в зависимости от роли пользователя будет вызывать ту или иную зависимую модель.